# Sort array of objects, using values inside each object (aggregation framework)

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have these documents:

```
[
  {
    '_id': 1,
    'roles': [
      {
        'k': 'free',
        'v': 1
      },
      {
        'k': 'pro',
        'v': 5
      },
      {
        'k': 'free',
        'v': 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    '_id': 2,
    'roles': [
      {
        'k': 'pro',
        'v': 1
      },
      {
        'k': 'free',
        'v': 3
      },
      {
        'k': 'free',
        'v': 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So for every `_id`, we have a array of documents called `roles`.
I need to sort inside the array `roles`, using the `v` field.

**Expected output:**

```
[
  {
    '_id': 1,
    'roles': [
      {
        'k': 'free',
        'v': 1
      },
      {
        'k': 'free',
        'v': 2
      }
      {
        'k': 'pro',
        'v': 5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    '_id': 2,
    'roles': [
      {
        'k': 'pro',
        'v': 1
      },
      {
        'k': 'free',
        'v': 2
      }
      {
        'k': 'free',
        'v': 3
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So I tried to use `$sort`:

```
{
  '$sort': {
     'roles.v': 1
  }
}
```

But it does not sort inside the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `$unwind` and `$group` to reconstruct.

```
([
  { $unwind: "$roles" },
  { $sort: { "roles.v": 1 }},
  { $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    roles: { $push: "$roles" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Yeah, this works like a charm. Thanks for this easy approach!

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort by _id and if $project is needed, this will work as well.

```
db.getCollection("collectionName").aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$roles" },
    { $sort: { "roles.v": 1 }},
    { $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        roles: { $push: "$roles" }
    }},
    {$project: {
        _id: "$_id",
        roles: "$roles"
    }},
    {$sort: {"_id": 1}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple mongdb method `$sortArray`
The code is this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      result: {
        $sortArray: {
          input: "$roles",
          sortBy: {
            v: 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: if you want _id also, just make ```_id : 1```